# How to color a plot with a vector

Tags: plotting

Suppose I have four dimensional data, i.e. at each point in the plane, I have two numbers associated with it. For example, `{{{1,1},{f[1,1],g[1,1]}},{{1,2},{f[1,2],g[1,2]}},...}`. My data would not make sense to plot as a vector field. Instead, I would like to color each point, where its darkness corresponds to the size of `f`, and its hue corresponds to `g`. So at the end of the day, it would look like a ContourPlot, where the ColorFunction takes the function values as input.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that seems to work:

```
customColor[xx_, yy_] := 
 Blend[{Hue[0, 1, yy], Hue[0.2, 1, yy], Hue[0.4, 1, yy], 
   Hue[0.6, 1, yy], Hue[0.8, 1, yy]}, xx]
dataTest = { {1, 1, 0.1, 0.3}, {1, 2, 1, 1}, {2, 1, 0.5, 0.1}, {2, 2, 
    0.7, 0}};
Graphics[{customColor[#3, #4], Rectangle[{#1, #2}]} & @@@ dataTest, 
 Frame -> True]
```